# How to upload a .crt or .jks certificate to Salesforce using API?

Tags: metadata-api

I would really like to upload a certificate to Salesforce via API. The https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_certificate.htm says it's possible. But I'm confused on the process.

What I did is:

1. uploaded a cert to Salesforce via UI
2. downloaded the cert with Metadata API
3. duplicated the cert with just giving new name/label
4. when I deploy `certificate` folder to an org a CSR appears in there. If I deploy the same cert one more time it doesn't do anything.

How to upload a .crt or .jks certificate to Salesforce using API?

Answer (score 0):

To upload a certificate to Salesforce using the API, you can use the Metadata API or the REST API. Here are the steps you can follow using the Metadata API:

1. Create a new folder in your local file system to store the certificate metadata. For example, you can create a folder called "certificates" and place the certificate file in it.
2. Create a new file called "package.xml" in the "certificates" folder and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <types>
      <members>MyCertificate</members>
      <name>Certificate</name>
   </types>
   <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

In this example, "MyCertificate" is the name of the certificate you want to upload. Change this name to match the name of your certificate.

3. Create a new file called "MyCertificate.cer" in the "certificates" folder and add the content of the .crt or .jks certificate to it.
4. Use the Metadata API to deploy the certificate metadata to your Salesforce org. You can use a tool like Workbench or Ant Migration Tool to do this. Here's an example of how to use Workbench:

- Open Workbench and select "Deploy" under "Metadata Deploy".
- Choose the "Single Package" option and select the "certificates" folder as the package directory.
- Click "Next" and then "Deploy" to upload the certificate metadata to your org.

5. After the metadata has been deployed, you can verify that the certificate has been uploaded by checking the Certificate Management page in your Salesforce org.

Note that when you upload a certificate with the same name as an existing certificate, Salesforce will not create a new certificate but will update the existing one. This is why you are seeing a CSR in the folder when you deploy the same cert one more time.

Comment: Doesn't work. Giving the /force-app/main/default/certs/bestCert.cer: Could not infer a metadata type
12:36:19.227 Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org error

Comment: The Workbench just silently error

Comment: It does not work for me either.